# bi-directional bar chart with annotation in python plotly

Tags: plotly-python

I have a pandas dataset with a toy version that can be created with this

```
#creating a toy pandas dataframe
s1 = pd.Series(['dont have a mortgage',-31.8,'have mortgage',15.65])
s2 = pd.Series(['have utility bill arrears',-21.45,'',0])
s3 = pd.Series(['have interest only mortgage',-19.59,'',0])
s4 = pd.Series(['bank with challenger bank',-19.24,'bank with a traditional bank',32.71])

df = pd.DataFrame([list(s1),list(s2),list(s3),list(s4)], columns = ['label1','value1','label2','value2'])
```

I want to create a bar chart that looks like this version I hacked together in excel

[image]

I want to be able to supply RGB values to customise the two colours for the left and right bars (currently blue and orange)

I tried different versions using “fig.add_trace(go.Bar” but am brand new to plotly and cant get anything to work with different coloured bars on one row with annotation under each bar.

All help greatly appreciated!

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a double-sided bar chart, you can create two subplots with shared x- and y-axis. Each subplot is a horizontal bar chart with a specified marker color

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

# define data set
s1 = pd.Series(['dont have a mortgage',-31.8,'have mortgage',15.65])
s2 = pd.Series(['have utility bill arrears',-21.45,'',0])
s3 = pd.Series(['have interest only mortgage',-19.59,'',0])
s4 = pd.Series(['bank with challenger bank',-19.24,'bank with a traditional bank',32.71])
df = pd.DataFrame([list(s1),list(s2),list(s3),list(s4)], columns = ['label1','value1','label2','value2'])

# create subplots
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, specs=[[{}, {}]], shared_xaxes=True,
                    shared_yaxes=True, horizontal_spacing=0)

fig.append_trace(go.Bar(y=df.index, x=df.value1, orientation='h', width=0.4, showlegend=False, marker_color='#4472c4'), 1, 1)
fig.append_trace(go.Bar(y=df.index, x=df.value2, orientation='h', width=0.4, showlegend=False, marker_color='#ed7d31'), 1, 2)
fig.update_yaxes(showticklabels=False) # hide all yticks
```

The annotations need to be added separately:

```
annotations = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.label1 != '':
        annotations.append({
            'xref': 'x1',
            'yref': 'y1',
            'y': i,
            'x': row.value1,
            'text': row.value1,
            'xanchor': 'right',
            'showarrow': False})
        annotations.append({
            'xref': 'x1',
            'yref': 'y1',
            'y': i-0.3,
            'x': -1,
            'text': row.label1,
            'xanchor': 'right',
            'showarrow': False})            
    if row.label2 != '':
        annotations.append({
            'xref': 'x2',
            'yref': 'y2',
            'y': i,
            'x': row.value2,
            'text': row.value2,
            'xanchor': 'left',
            'showarrow': False})  
        annotations.append({
            'xref': 'x2',
            'yref': 'y2',
            'y': i-0.3,
            'x': 1,
            'text': row.label2,
            'xanchor': 'left',
            'showarrow': False})

fig.update_layout(annotations=annotations)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Hi @Pascalo - great thanks!  Quick question -  how do I force the bars to be plotted in the same order as they are in the dataframe?  The order seems to be reversed in the charts.  So I reverse the dataframe and yet the row order in the chart remains.  Ideally the row order in the dataframe  becomes the row order in the chart.  Thanks again.